# how to make a exe to add user in usergroup in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, exe, sharepoint-2007

I have 5 groups in share-point 2013 and I want to add 10000 user using program and than to make a exe of them so that when client install that exe in his PC the user will automatically gets installed in SharePoint group.I am reading a excel file which contains user id and than trying to insert it SharePoint User Directory. How to achieve it?

```
User ID | User group
  1         AA
  2         BB
  3         CC
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the approach your suggest isn't efficient enough. If we follow your approach:

1) we have to develop a Exe Program (3-4 hours)

2) User Download Exe File

3) User Execute the Exe File

may I suggest this way instead?

1) Go to the SharePoint Group

2) Click on Group Settings

3) Allow requests to join/leave this group? Select "Yes"

4) Auto-accept requests? Select "Yes"

after that you just need to include the SharePoint Group Link and send email to that 10000 users for them to get the access their self.

Comment: I need to add the User to groups. Their are 36000 user in 10 groups.

Comment: they have a limit for SPGroup, the number of user shouldn't over 5000.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29755/sharepoint-group-having-more-than-5000-users-in-a-group 

instead of sharepoint group, we should use domain group to optimize the performance.